# Glassfish v2.1.1 clustering error

Tags: glassfish

I'm trying to configure glassfish to use clusters. I have created node agent, two clusters and for each cluster one instance which refers to create node agent. I started domain and now I'm trying to start node agent using command: asadmin start-node-agent myNodeAgent but the start up fails.

In server logs I see this error:

```
The NodeAgent failed to complete the intial synchronization with the DAS.  Please make sure the DAS is running and is accessible from the NodeAgents server|#]
```

I tried to google, but I can not find anything useful.

Maybe someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node agent can't seem to contact the DAS.  Have you properly set up name services?  From the host the node agent is running on, can you ping the DAS host by its name and IP address?

Is the DAS running?

When you created the node agent, did you specify the correct DAS host and port name? Example:
NodeAgentHost> asadmin create-node-agent --host DasHost --port 4848  MyNodeAgent

Comment: This was the problem, I recreated nodeagent using this command asadmin create-node-agent --host DasHost --port 4848 MyNodeAgent and it is working. Thank you.